# does nobody care about beta?

Tags: discussion, stackexchange, beta

I've been a member of Salesforce StackExchnge for over a year now and yet it is still in beta, the site stats look good and don't see any reason why it should still be in beta. Can anyone explain to me the process of moving out of beta?

Comment: I completely agree with you, check out this topic:  [Salesforce StackExchange Should No Longer Be In Beta](http://meta.salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/420/salesforce-stackexchange-should-no-longer-be-in-beta)

Comment: I think everyone agrees with you here that we should be taken out of beta. There isn't anything the community can do to make this process any faster at this point.

Comment: I can appreciate your frustration with the delays. The Salesforce site has effectively "graduated", but there has a been a backlog in getting the design out. Please see the updates in the linked post. <fingers crossed> that we can move forward with the design soon.